# Simple PHP list of words to HTML ordered list

Tags: php

so my words is below, separated by space.  my code is 1st line is grabbed from text file & whole line is echoed, instead i need each-word as ordered list.

> • bombay new_delhi chennai culcutta

```
<?php
$z = file('q1.txt'); echo $z[1]; echo (mt_rand(1,9)); 

$st = array($z[1]);
foreach($st as $ls) {echo "  <li>$ls</li>\n";}
```

i need like this

> • bombay
>
> • new_delhi
>
> • chennai
>
> • culcutta

Answer (score 1):

Before the `foreach()`

```
echo '<ol>';
//foreach loop
echo '</ol>';
```

Comment: its not working.. still whole line echoed. i need each word in each line okay.

Comment: You aren't doing it right. I won't write the whole code for you. The above code I added won't put everything in one line. What do you have?

Comment: ok(y) <?php
$z = file('q1.txt'); echo $z[1]; echo (mt_rand(1,9)); 

$c=  explode(" ", $z[1]);
echo '<ol>';
foreach($c as $w) {echo " <li>$w</li>\n";}
echo '</ol>';

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$z = file('q1.txt'); echo $z[1]; echo (mt_rand(1,9)); 

$c=  explode(" ", $z[1]);
echo '<ol>';
foreach($c as $w) {echo " <li>$w</li>\n";}
echo '</ol>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = file('q1.txt'); 
$abc = explode(' ', $var);

echo '<ul style=" list-style-type: circle;">';
foreach($abc as $value){
  echo " <li>$value</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```